# Why does my shell script hang without the .sh extension?

Tags: bash, scripts

I created a shell script `/usr/local/bin/suspend` with the following content:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Take an optional delay parameter
if [ "$#" -gt "0" ]; then
  sleep "$1"
fi

# Put the system to sleep
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.Hal" \
    /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer \
    org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Suspend \
    int32:0
```

If I `chmod +x` and run the script by invoking it directly (e.g., just typing `suspend` or `/usr/local/bin/suspend` on the command line), nothing happens and the shell hangs—it doesn't even respond to Ctrl-C; I have to switch to a new shell and kill the `bash` process (which has no apparent children).

The script works fine if I invoke it in any of the following ways:

- Using `sh /usr/local/bin/suspend`.
- Using `. /usr/local/bin/suspend`.
- Renaming it to `suspend.sh` and invoking `/usr/local/bin/suspend.sh` (or just `suspend.sh`, since it's in the `PATH`).

The last option is fine, but still I wonder: what exactly is wrong with not using the `.sh` extension?

Comment: Remember you can use "which command" to know what exactly is run when you issue "command".

Comment: `which` didn't help, because `suspend` is a builtin.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for the Unix & Linux SE site. There is nothing Ubuntu specific about this question.

Comment: Except that I'm a member of this community and I'm not a member of that community and I didn't support the creation of two sites precisely because I didn't want to waste time addressing comments like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`suspend` is a bash builtin,

```
suspend: suspend [-f]
Suspend shell execution.

Suspend the execution of this shell until it receives a SIGCONT signal.
Unless forced, login shells cannot be suspended.

Options:
  -f    force the suspend, even if the shell is a login shell

Exit Status:
Returns success unless job control is not enabled or an error occurs.
```

and as builtins take precedence, just typing `suspend` would behave exactly as you describe: the shell blocks until you kill it (if you `kill -CONT` it, it resumes).

That you're seeing this same behavior by invoking it with the path is either an experimental error, or a bug in the shell. I'd suspect the former before the latter.

Comment: I suspected something like this might be the case, but `which suspend` and `man suspend` both returned nothing. The former isn't surprising, because `which` doesn't handle builtins, but the latter is irritating.

Comment: `help suspend` is the ticket.

Comment: `which` is a useless command. Use the builtin `type` instead. Try, `type suspend`, `type -a suspend` and `type -P suspend`. `help type` to learn more. But really, just avoid naming your scripts with the name of a shell builtin.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your command to supercede a builtin, you first have to disable the builtion:

```
enable -n suspend
```

You can then run your command like a normal command.
Then, you re-enable the builtin

```
enable suspend
```

I'm surprised the builtin is invoked when you call your command with the full path.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the sh extension; it is actually the opposite, you should not be using it.

> Don't use extensions for your scripts. Scripts define new commands that you can run, and commands are generally not given extensions. Also: bash script are *not* sh script (so don't use .sh) and the extension will only cause dependencies headaches if the script gets rewritten in another language.

From *#bash on Freenode.net*