# Would it be possible to minimize current window with hotkey Super+<number_of_window_in_launcher>?

Tags: unity, launcher, window, minimize

I've been searching about this feature and I didn't found anything. For me is quite intuitive this combo. If you can rise an application from his launcher shortcut, why don't do the same to minimize it?

As far as I know I have to conform myself with Alt+F9...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the launcher to minimize applications by design. Neither with the mouse nor a keyboard shortcut. See [Can I use the Unity launcher icon to minimize applications/windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36433/why-cant-i-use-the-unity-launcher-icon-to-minimize-applications-windows)