# unity window launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I use the Unity launcher icon to minimize applications/windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36433/why-cant-i-use-the-unity-launcher-icon-to-minimize-applications-windows)

What is the easiest way to make unity 3D reduce an application if the icon is clicked upon in the launcher and the window is already on top ?

As far as I know, in such a case, clicking doesn't do anything. If it does do something that I'm unaware of, please do explain it to me, maybe it's a feature I am interested in but just haven't noticed.