# Minimize/Maximize window behavior

Tags: taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I use the Unity launcher icon to minimize applications/windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36433/why-cant-i-use-the-unity-launcher-icon-to-minimize-applications-windows)

On *Windows*, when I click on a taskbar icon the window maximizes, and when I click on it again it minimizes.

On *Ubuntu*, when I click on a taskbar icon the window maximizes, when I click on it again it does nothing ( I have to manually click on the minimize button).

Is there a way to attain the same behavior like on windows?

> Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS